# How can I split an existing bag in ros2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an already existing bag and I would like to split it by time in ros2? I don't want a newly recorded bag to always be split after a certain size or time, but an already existing bag to be split after a certain time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366887/how-can-i-split-an-existing-bag-in-ros2?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is currently impossible, see feature request here: https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/issues/599

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0